# PHP Contact Form not sending and not getting parse errors

Tags: php

I have built a PHP contact form for a site. The server has the mailer enabled and the code will not execute. I'm not receiving any parse errors. Any suggestions on dubugging or what the issue is?

```
//Check the form submission
if (isset($POST['submitted'])){
//validate the form
if(!empty($_POST['name']) &&
!empty($_POST['email']) && 
!empty($_POST['comments']) ){

//Create the body
$body = "Name:
{$_POST['name']}\n\nComments:
{$_POST['comments']}";



//Make the Name no longer than 70 Characters
$body = wordwrap($body, 70);

//Send the email
mail('xxx@xxxx.com',
'Contact Form Submission',$body,
"From: {$_POST['email']}");

//Print the Thank You message
echo'<p>Thank you for contacting us we appreciate your interest</p>';


//Clear $_POST so that its not a sticky form
$_POST = array();
} else {
echo'<p>Please fill out the form completely.</p>';
}
}// End of main isset ()IF
```

The form code is

```
<div id="wrapper">
<p>Please fill out this form to contact us.</p>
<form action="contact.php"method="post">
<p>Name: <input type="text" name="name"size="30"maxlength="60"value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name']))echo $_POST['name']; ?>" /></p>

<p>Email Address: <input type="text" name="email"size="30"maxlength="80"value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email']))echo $_POST['email']; ?>" /></p>

<p>Comments: <textarea name="comments"rows="5"cols="30"><?php if(isset($_POST['comments']))echo $_POST['comments']; ?></textarea></p>

<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" /> </p>

<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE"/>

</form>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please provide the form code. Can you explain more what you need. The problem is that the mail is not sending. What you see after filling the form?.

Comment: Check your mail relay logs to see if anything is getting sent out.

Comment: Have you checked the returnvalue of mail()?

Comment: Do you have display errors enabled?

Comment: Have you testing the mail function on it's own?  Create a test.php file with just `<?php mail('keith@kamtechnologyconsulting.com', 'Test Email', 'This is a test email.'); ?>` See if that works to rule out a problem with the server and mail function.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with removing the curly braces from the extra headers and add `\r\n` like this:

```
if(mail('keith@kamtechnologyconsulting.com',
        'Contact Form Submission',$body,
        "From: ".$_POST['email']."\r\n")) {
    echo "Thank you message";
} else {
    //Maybe some appropriate logging and an errormessage here.
}
```

You could ofcourse go with something more advanced and use something like [PHPMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) instead.

Comment: Thanks you. I followed your suggestion but for some reason its now giving me a parse error with "From: ".$_POST['email']."\r\n");) { any suggestions?

Comment: Ah a stupid misstake of mine remove the `;` in the if statement. Sorry about that. But that is a lovely example of why copy-paste-programming is bad. :P